# how can I use webpack plugins to create a directory and copy files to it?

Tags: webpack, package.json

I am using webpack but in *package.json* I have been running this prestart script:

```
rm -rf dev && mkdir dev && cp -R pages/* dev && cp -R theme dev
```

That was great running on my mac at home. But I also need to run this on my surface and I'm not sure how to make this work.

I tried a variety of things to make the script just run on the PC including *Cygwin* and have decided to proceed with *webpack* plugins. I found one to delete the dev directory as part of a clean process, but also need to remake the dev directory and then copy files into it.

Here is my current webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require("path");
var webpack = require("webpack");
var target = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event;
var paths = {
  src: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
  dev: path.join(__dirname, "dev"),
  dist: path.join(__dirname, "dist")
};

module.exports = {
  context: paths.src,

  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    path: paths.dev,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
      loaders: [{
        test: /.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel'

      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
      }]
  },
  plugins: [
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './'
  }
};
```

Any suggestions with description of how to configure them would be very appreciated. I spent about 3 hours trying to make it work yesterday and did not get beyond the delete of the folder. The copy plugin I selected may be working but the directory never gets created, so I'm not sure.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking for DOS equivalents?

Comment: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net and make sure the directory you install them into is in your `%path%`.

Comment: I'm more interested in having my webpack configured to do this directory drop and copy than I am in doing some sort of hack to have the bash code run. I played with two plugins and have be able to delete the dev folder, but am still struggling with the creation of the directory and the copy of the theme and pages folders from source to dev